Проблема с кодировкой на сайте
У меня возникла пробелма. При разработке сайта на локалхосте, отображалось все корректно, но когда я перенес сайт на хостинг, то кириллица отображается в виде знаков вопросов:

Но на другой части сайта (отдельная от той, которая на скриншоте) все отображается корректно:

Код страницы с первого скрина:
<?php
require "../config.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Школьник.Сайт</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        require "schoolhead.php";

        // Защита от SQL-инъекций
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT school FROM users WHERE login = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $acclogin);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();
        
        if ($res && $res->num_rows > 0) {
            $school = $res->fetch_assoc()['school'];
        } else {
            echo "<p>Информация об организации не найдена.</p>";
            exit;
        }
    ?>
    <h1>Ваша организация (<?php echo htmlspecialchars($school); ?>)</h1>
    <?php
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM schools WHERE orgshort = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $school);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($res && $res->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

            $director = htmlspecialchars($row['director']);
            $directoremail = htmlspecialchars($row['directoremail']);
            $orgfull = htmlspecialchars($row['orgfull']);
            $orgshort = htmlspecialchars($row['orgshort']);
            $funddate = htmlspecialchars($row['funddate']);
            $orgtype = htmlspecialchars($row['orgtype']);
        } else {
            echo "<p>Информация об организации не найдена.</p>";
            $director = $directoremail = $orgfull = $orgshort = $funddate = $orgtype = '';
        }
    ?>
    <p>Полное наименование: <?php echo $orgfull; ?></p>
    <p>Краткое наименование: <?php echo $orgshort; ?></p>
    <p>ФИО директора: <?php echo $director; ?>; почта: <?php echo $directoremail; ?></p>
    <p>Тип организации: <?php echo $orgtype; ?></p>
    <p>Дата основания: <?php echo $funddate; ?></p>
    <?php
        if($currentrole == "Директор" || $currentrole == "Администратор"){
            echo "<a href='https://vk.com/ais_shkolnik'><button>Подключить блог</button></a>";
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>


Код со второго скрина:
<?php
    require "../config.php";
    if($currentrole != "ОУ"){
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }

    if(!isset($_GET["view"])){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $school = $_GET["view"];

    $res = $conn->query("SELECT orgshort FROM organs WHERE directorname = '$currentfullname'");
    $organ = $res->fetch_assoc()['orgshort'];

    $res = $conn->query("SELECT organ FROM schools WHERE orgshort = '$school'");
    $schoolorgan = $res->fetch_assoc()['organ'];

    if ($schoolorgan != $organ){
       header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $school;?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="https://shkolnik.site/organ" style='display:flex;justify-content:center;'><img src="<?php echo $site?>/img/logo.png" alt="Ш" style='width:24px;height:24px;'>кольник</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <?php
        $res = $conn->query("SELECT director, directorlogin, directoremail, orgfull, orgshort, funddate, orgtype, isblog FROM schools WHERE orgshort = '$school'");
        $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

        $director = $row['director'];
        $directorlogin = $row['directorlogin'];
        $directoremail = $row['directoremail'];
        $orgfull = $row['orgfull'];
        $orgshort = $row['orgshort'];
        $funddate = $row['funddate'];
        $orgtype = $row['orgtype'];
        $isblog = $row['isblog'];
    ?>
    <h2>Просмотр сведений об <?php echo $school;?>:</h2>
    <?php
        echo "<p>ФИО директора: $director</p>";
        echo "<p>Почта директора: $directoremail</p>";
        echo "<p>Полное наименование: $orgfull</p>";
        echo "<p>Краткое наименование: $orgshort</p>";
        echo "<p>Дата основания: $funddate</p>";
        echo "<p>Тип организации: $orgtype</p>";
        if ($isblog){
            echo "<p>Блог подключен</p>";
        } else{
            echo "<p>Блог не подключен</p>";
        }
    ?>
__ остальной код__
</html>

В .htaccess прописана кодировка UTF-8:
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Также, все файлы сохранены в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM

Может у поля/тблички кодировка неправильная?

@OliverPatterson кодировка в БД utf8mb4_general_ci

Пробовали $conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");?

@OliverPatterson да, но не помогает

Также пробовал header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8"); setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');

А если убрать htmlspecialchars?

@OliverPatterson не помогло

А где вы генерируете ссылку для втого скрина?

Какую ссылку? @OliverPatterson

Ну на втором скрине же другая страница, на нее же нужно как-то попасть,, значит есть ссылка, для которой вы заедете в get параметрах view.

        if($res->num_rows>0){
            echo "<center><table border='1' style='margin-bottom:15px;'>";
            echo "<tr><td>Кр. наименование</td></tr>";
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td><button><a href='check.php?view=" . urlencode($row['orgshort']) . "'>" .$row['orgshort']."</a></button></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table></center>";
        }```
